# Please write more tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm a bit of a casual user. I don't load the front page of this site every day. It's more a case of if I have a question, I come here, ask a question, and hope I get a good answer.

In my question [Do "100% renewable" electricity plans increase renewable electricity production?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/679/179), I wasn't sure whether to use [energy](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) or [electricity](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity), so took the hyper-consumerist-style option: using both.

If there were tag wikis, it'd be easier to determine which one I should use. Even if it's something as simple as "Use energy for cars, and electricity for household appliances".

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right! We should write more tag wikis. **I call upon all users (with at least 100 rep) to [choose one tag](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tags) that hasn't got a wiki yet and write it**.

The excerpt of a tag should make clear for what kind of questions/topics the tag should be used. Note that the excerpt is plain text with a maximum of 500 characters.

If you have the time you can also add a full description of a tag. This part may contain Markdown (unlike the excerpt) and should explain in more detail how to use the tag, but also contain some general background information on the subject. You can also add links to useful external sources (e.g. wikipedia)

Remember, when you are writing a tag wiki don't juse copy content written by others without attribution. More information about how to write a good tag wiki can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337/164138).