# Please contribute to tag wikis (2021)

Tags: discussion, tags

Hello Sustainable Living community!

Our site has a many tags that could benefit from the addition of tag wikis and excerpts. Please consider contributing your expertise and writing skills to help improve the tags on this site. To help get you started, here's a short selection of tags that currently have no excerpt at all.

- [electric-vehicles](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicles) and [hybrid-vehicles](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hybrid-vehicles)
- [hydroelectricity](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydroelectricity)
- [glass](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glass)
- [cement](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cement)
- [fossil-fuels](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fossil-fuels) such as [coal](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coal) and [natural-gas](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-gas)
- [printing](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printing)

Beyond these, there are [many more tags](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name) that could also benefit from new and improved tag wikis.

### Help! I've never written a tag wiki before.

First time? That means you're eligible to claim the shiny ✨ [image: A picture of the Tag Editor badge.] ✨ badge.

There's a great FAQ page about [how to write a great tag excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts). Here are the highlights:

> 1. The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.
> 2. Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag.
> 3. Concentrate on what a tag means to *your* community.
> 4. Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.

To get started, just click any tag link (eg. [electric-vehicles](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicles)) then click the "help us create it" link where the tag excerpt normally appears.

Here's a few well-written examples to inspire you: [carbon-footprint](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbon-footprint) [gardening](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening) [ecological-footprint](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecological-footprint) [paper](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper).

### Collaborate in the answers

If you prefer a more collaborative approach, consider drafting your tag wiki as an answer on this post. *(Just one answer per tag, please!)* The community can help with suggestions in the comments, and I'll help make sure your proposed edits are accepted.

Comment: It's been more than six years since [the last request for tag wikis](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/please-write-more-tag-wikis) so I figured it was time to renew the call. :-)

Comment: Very good initiative! I took the liberty to make this a featured post.

Answer (score 1):

### [Top Tags without excerpts](https://data.stackexchange.com/sustainability/query/1460499/top-tags-without-excerpts)

This is an Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) query to track which tags see the most use, and don't have tag excerpts. The top 15 (as of writing) are below. Please feel free to edit the list to remove ones that are done, and add new ones from the query above:

| Tag | Question Count |
| --- | --- |
| [electric-vehicles](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicles) | 29 |
| [clothing](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing) | 26 |
| [waste-minimisation](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waste-minimisation) | 25 |
| [biodegradable-waste](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biodegradable-waste) | 24 |
| [air-conditioning](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioning) | 23 |
| [cleaning](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) | 23 |
| [farming](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farming) | 23 |
| [energy-use](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-use) | 22 |
| [air-pollution](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-pollution) | 21 |
| [food-storage](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-storage) | 21 |
| [manufacturing](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacturing) | 20 |
| [energy-management](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-management) | 19 |
| [natural-gas](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-gas) | 19 |
| [consumption](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consumption) | 18 |
| [oil](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil) | 18 |

Do note that SEDE is updated weekly, so be careful adding in tags that already have excerpts.

Comment: This is something we've [used on Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1595/28182) for a few years now, and it's helped immensely. I hope it's as useful here too :)

Comment: Thanks! That's an excellent SEDE query!